# Numpy 2D array to Table

Tags: python, numpy

I've got an 18x18 2d numpy array (it's a confusion matrix)...and I need/would like to display it as a table in an ipython notebook.

When I simply print it out, it displays with overlap--the rows are so long they take up two lines.

Is there a library that will allow me to print this array in a sort of spreadsheet format?

Comment: you could try to load it into a pandas dataframe. that should look much better.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) for that.

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.DataFrame(yourArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

A job for [matrepr](https://pypi.org/project/matrepr/):

```py
from matrepr import mdisplay

mat = np.random.random((18, 18))

mdisplay(mat, floatfmt=".2f", max_rows=18, max_cols=18)
```

[image: matrepr html output]

Answer (score -2):

**Note**: 
Konstantinos proposal holds only for 1-D and 2-D arrays!

You can use `numpy.array2string()`:

```
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(np.array2string(array).replace('[[',' [').replace(']]',']'))
```

Output:

```
 [1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
```

**See also:** [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)