# how to fill up a table row by row in python? I tried append but it didn't work

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I want to find all combinations of numbers {0,1,2,3,4}, and print them out in a table, with the first column being the order number and the second column being a particular combination. My desired output should take the following form:

1 (0,)

2 (1,)

... ...

6 (0,1)

... ...

I tried the following codes

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
rows=list(range(5))
combrows=[]
for k in range(1,5):  #the number of rows k takes values from 1 to 5
    for combo in itertools.combinations(rows,k):
        combrows.append(combo)

ind=1
store=[]
for i in combrows:
    store.append([[ind],[i]])
    ind=ind+1
print(store)
```

But the resulting table is a horizontal line instead of a 2D rectangular table with two columns. How could I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/35684318/17635987 ?

Comment: @kirjosieppo Thanks! I just added my desired output in the question. Do you think this could be accomplished using the link you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite straightforward solution:

```py
from itertools import combinations
numbers = list(range(5))
lst = []
for l in (combinations(numbers, r) for r in range(1, 5)):
    lst.extend(l)
for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    print(i+1, j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsJADEX3c4osM1gEETeCJxEXraaaMpOUTAQ9/TjVLvzLz3tvfvtDZV/raJqBncxVUwHOs5rDVfPA0jurlCDPPJAVOEHi4mi93AkPMYZUvJ3nSxjVIAEL4L@Iq9iBRVgQW5CfvuugFY4B2lpmSy8nuWGK3xZ3MC0stQJZ74SNWenZWBx50wpTDLV@AA)

`enumerate` generates the line numbers automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful, and completely solved my problem. Indeed storing data in a 2D table via filling up row by row is not needed. Printing two objects at a time is enough.